# Use Python class in another file, with packages it uses

Tags: python, qt, class, pyqt

I'm really new to Python and its usage.

I created a Python UI with PyQt.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 692)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8(""))
        ...
        ...

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "x", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "x", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works well when I run the command `python main1.py`
Now I want the seperate UI class from the file to use multiple UI classes with a single `__main__`

I removed all parts except the Ui_MainWindow class and created a new `main.py` file such that:

```
from main1 import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can reach the class and create object. But when I run the `python main.py` command, I see this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main1 import *
  File "/home/x/main1.py", line 38
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc4' in file /home/x/main1.py on line 38, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I think the problem is wrong usage of the `_fromUtf8` variable. How can it be solved or how should I approach the problem? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the question of the encoding you use in your editor in file main1.py.

There is a character hexadecimal `c4` that is > 128 so ascii can not be used.

Try some to put one of the following encoding lines into one of the first lines of main1.py. (I recommend the last one) and try to find out the encoding of that file and set it.

```
      # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-


      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-


      #!/usr/bin/python
      # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      # I recommend utf8!
```

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: I did, now the problem is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  File "/home/x/main1.py", line 6, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
NameError: global name '_fromUtf8' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, what is the content of `main1.py`? Then I can help further.. the function `_fromUtf8` is not available there.

Comment: The content of main1.py exists in the question. _fromUtf8 is available when I run `python main1.py`, but is not when I import main1 to main and run it, and that is the problem.

Comment: Your traceback ` File "/home/x/main1.py", line 6` confuses me... it does not match the files posted above.. I do not see an error in these lines so could you update the question?

Comment: line 6 of main1.py file is `MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))`, which is the first usage of `_fromUtf8()`